# Session vs. SQL Query vs. Cache | User Object

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

In my System I'm using an Object `User` to store all the needed UserData which I get from the Database.

In the Session I'm storing the User ID. On Page call I query the User Data from the DB and store it into the `User`-Object.

Now I saw somebody storing all the `User`-Object into the Session.

I wondered what's the better way?

I saw [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496478/trade-off-between-user-data-in-session-vs-database) here on SO, which helped a bit.

But 2 Things:

1. To lower the risk of Session-Hijacking I'm creating a new Session on every Page Load. Therefore all the Data from the Session Object gets transferred.
2. Somewhere else I saw that PHP 5 has an Cache already in the Pack. So Does it automatically store the User Object?

Comment: Is your question "does PHP5 automatically cache the User object"? Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Yeah mainly and whats the better way to store the user data